# Sack Sum By operation causes AWS Neptune error

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

**Problem up-front**:  AWS Neptune seems to break when using a `.sack(__.sum).by()` operation.

**Background**:

- [Here is a small bit of data](https://gist.github.com/danshev/3d5641e8d1bf1be9aa8742ee4f4ebc10) on which to test
- [The query](https://gist.github.com/danshev/07c059c6ffd683c745a4c62ee6ec768e) in question ***works fine via the Gremlin console***
- I came across this [tackling a larger problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72198242/gremlin-shortest-logistical-route-between-a-and-b-while-respecting-schedules), but the length of that post (and my multiple updates to it...) were burying the problem, so I'm posting this here, separately.

**Conditions**

- **Data store**: AWS Neptune
- **Querying from / runtime**: AWS Lambda running Node.js

Given the above, this query will execute:

```
return await g.withSack(120)
 .V(fromPortId)
 .repeat(
     (__.outE().hasLabel('VOYAGES_TO'))
     .inV()
     .simplePath()
 )
 .until(
     __.has('code', toPortId).and()
     .sack().is(lte(travelTimeBudget))
 )
 .order().by(__.sack(), __.desc)
 .local(
     __.union(__.path().by('code')
     .by('duration'), __.sack()).fold()
 )
 .local(
     __.unfold().unfold().fold()
 )
 .toList()
 .then(data => {
     return data
 })
 .catch(error => {
     console.log('ERROR', error);
 });
```

... **but this query will not**:

```
return await g.withSack(120)
 .V(fromPortId)
 .repeat(
     (__.outE().hasLabel('VOYAGES_TO').sack(__.sum).by('duration'))
     .sack(__.sum).by(__.constant(45))
     .inV()
     .simplePath()
 )
 .until(
     __.has('code', toPortId).and()
     .sack().is(lte(travelTimeBudget))
 )
 .order().by(__.sack(), __.desc)
 .local(
     __.union(__.path().by('code')
     .by('duration'), __.sack()).fold()
 )
 .local(
     __.unfold().unfold().fold()
 )
 .toList()
 .then(data => {
     return data
 })
 .catch(error => {
     console.log('ERROR', error);
 });
```

... and the only difference between the two is the presence of the `.sack(__.sum).by()` operators.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting an error or just not the expected result? Also what values should be used  for `fromPortId` and `travelTimeBudget` in order to reproduce the results?

Comment: Also, your should not use `__.sum` inside `sack` as that is the actual `sum()` step and not the operator `sum`. You should ideally include those at the top of your code. Alternatively us `Operator.sum`. I'll add this as an answer below with an example.

Comment: You were correct -- `operator.sum` was needed.  For anyone using the Javascript gremlin SDK, use `const { operator } = gremlin.process;` to bring it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `__.sum` inside a `sack` step, as that is the actual `sum()` step (from the anonymous traversal `__.`) and not the `Operator.sum` enum. You should ideally include those at the top of your code, alternatively use:

```java
     (__.outE().hasLabel('VOYAGES_TO').sack(operator.sum).by('duration'))
     .sack(operator.sum).by(__.constant(45))
```

The additional parentheses around this block of code should also not be needed.

Comment: Continued thanks, @Kelvin -- I did find that the wrapping parentheses are needed, otherwise I get an error about the repeat() not being complete.  Also (minor), in the Javascript gremlin SDK, it's a lowercase `operator`